# How to list files and folders from path to tree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have tried that code to list directory to tree

I set `name = "D:/folder"`

folder directory have many files and folders

but all I got as result is one node with name(folder)

```
public class tree {
    JTree tree;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node1;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode temp;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode temp2;
    DefaultTreeModel model;
    String name = new currentfolder().getInitial(); // path to directory that its
                                                    // content appear in tree
    public tree() {
        tree = new JTree();
        node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
        temp = node1;
        import_data(new File(name));
        temp.setParent(node1);
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(node1);
        tree.setModel(model);
        model.reload();
        tree.setOpaque(false);
        tree.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
          new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(
          javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED),
          javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("")));
          tree.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void import_data(File file)    {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            temp2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
            temp2.setParent(temp);
            return;
        } else {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if (!file.getName().equals(name)) {
                    temp2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
                    temp2.setParent(temp);
                    temp = temp2;
                }
            File[] f = file.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                import_data(f[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so how can I fix that?

it will be better if there is fix for that code else another way then to list to tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a node into the tree, you need to call `DefaultMutableTreeNode.add` (`temp.add(temp2)`). Calling `setParent()` will not add a node into the tree.

Also you need to change `import_data` so that it takes two parameters: the `File` for the directory and the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` corresponding to the directory.

Comment: i tried 
    temp.add(temp2);
but it gives the same result as temp will get new value from next line(temp = temp2;)

Comment: Giving your variables names which are not "temp" and "temp2" will surely make your code easier to understand.

Comment: yah xD
because that is version 1 methods

Comment: thnx i didnt think about that 
well do u know what TreeModelFile do?

Comment: I don't know of anything called "TreeModelFile".